# xamarin android receiving one simple sentence/string from webservice

Tags: xamarin.android, httprequest

I am trying to receive one simple sentence from a webservice, but I have something wrong.

This is my async task to request from the webservice:

```
private async Task<string> GetData (string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "text/plain";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                string doc = await Task.Run(() => stream.ToString());
                return doc;
            }
        }

    }
```

And this is my button:

```
cmd02.Click += async (sender, e) => {
            string sentence = await GetData(url);
            txt01.Text = sentence;
        };
```

I get only "System.Net.WebConnectionStream" into my TextView and don´t know which function I should use. Or maybe everthing is wrong?

Maybe somebody has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static async Task<string> SendGetRequestAsync (string url) {

            string responseString = "";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            HttpWebResponse response;

            await Task.Run (() => {
                try {
                    response = request.GetResponse () as HttpWebResponse;
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ())) {
                        responseString = reader.ReadToEnd ();
                    }
                } catch (WebException ex) {

                    Console.WriteLine (ex);
                }
            });

            return responseString;
        }
```